# C++, callbacks, objects and best practice

Tags: c++, c, qt, callback

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I found a workaround but I feel there should be a prettier way of doing this. Here's my problem:
I have an IPC library written in C. When message is received, it calls a callback function. I made a wrapper class on this library. When the message is received, the wrapper class should trigger a signal (I'm using Qt yes). As you know, member function can't be a callback, so in my case, I wrote that callback outside the class. Now I have to emit a signal from the callback function, the only way I know is to make a public method for the wrapper class which will emit the signal, but I don't want to have that method public, and I can't access protected/private members outside the class.
Anyone had similar problem? How did you solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a friend function work, as you wont have to make your method public then? [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html)

Comment: @Sim, please post your comment as answer, so I can mark it as answer :) Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your outside funktion as a friend of that class and therefore wont need to make the method public.

Here a [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html) to a tutorial.

Postet as an answer as requested in comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want member function as 'callback' you can declare that function as 'static' in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a member function *can* be a callback, with some additional work. This is something which is called "delegate". You could try `boost::bind`/[`boost::mem_fn`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html). Maybe some other libraries will be more convenient/helpful, e.g., [boost.lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/lambda.html) (I didn't try it).

Answer (score 0):

The std::mem_fun does the same trick as Vlad pointed. Making friends considered not a good design, since you are exposing all your class internals to be potentially accessible without even calling a member.

Static method will not be able to emit a singal, but it can access another static member pointing to your class. You could create a special "caller" class that way, storing a single static pointer to your Qt object.

You could have a global class pointer, but it's even worse than having a friend. You could make your class singleton, but it is similar to global variable in its tradeoffs, so doesn't worth it just for one use.